# Is there a way to achieve covariance of generic types in C# 3.0?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, covariance

This has been introduced in C# 4.0, but is there a way to achieve this in c# 3.0?

For e.g., consider the following code:

```
class Base
{
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
}

class User<T> where T : Base
{
}

class User1 : User<Derived1>
{
}
```

Now, I would like to have a list of `User<T>`, in which I can store `User<Derived1>` as well as `User<Derived2>`, but the following code fails to compile in C# 3.0:

```
List<User<Base>> users = new List<User<Base>>();
users.Add(new User1());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you could achieve it in C# 3, they wouldn't have needed to introduce it in C# 4. Also, there's no such thing as C# 3.5. It's C# 3.0, .NET 3.5.

Comment: @John: Points taken - both of them. :P. Is there a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is to make the list less specific. The least specific you could do is List<object>. Something better would perhaps be to create an IUser interface that your user class implements, and then you can have List<IUser>. Another workaround would be to use C# 4. ;)

Comment: @Tim - presumably you're joking, but note that F# doesn't support variance at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is there no good workaround, but your code also won't work in C# 4.0 - only interfaces and delegates support variance, so you will never be able to treat a `User<Derived>` as a `User<Base>`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably to use an `ArrayList` or `List<object>` and handle the casting yourself. There's no elegant way to do it in C# 3.